# maven-checkstyle-plugin: Unable to parse suppressions.xml - invalid formats or checks format

Tags: eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I am trying to add a suppressions.xml to my eclipse java project. My checkstyle-config.xml is in src/main/resources and suppressions.xml is in the same directory. I added this to the config file:

```xml
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="src/main/resources/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

And in pom.xml, I have

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <propertiesLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.build.properties</propertiesLocation>
        <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>                    
        <suppressionsLocation>src/main/resources/suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn verify` from command-line OR through eclipse m2e plugin, I get this error:

> Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module SuppressionFilter - Cannot set property 'file' in module SuppressionFilter to 'src/main/resources/suppressions.xml': unable to parse src/main/resources/suppressions.xml - invalid files or checks format: InvocationTargetException -> [Help 1]

I even tried to change the path in checkstyle-config.xml to `${config_log}` or `${basedir}` but no luck so far.

Any help on this would be appreciable.

**Update:** I feel that the issue might not be with the file location but with the suppressions.xml file itself. Here is my suppressions.xml,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
     "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="JavadocPackage" files="src/test/java/**"/>
</suppressions>
```

Comment: The docs say the file can be specified as on the classpath if you want. Try `supressions.xml` alone since src/main/resources has files that end up on a classpath root. Thats for the entry in the config file. i'm not sure if the entry in the pom is the same. I'm not sure why you would need it in both places.

Comment: I always put my checkstyle.xml config file in the same folder as the pom.xml file. Perhaps if you put both it and the suppressions.xml files there and just put their names without path in the pom, it might work.

Comment: Tried that and didn't work. I removed it from pom.xml and changed it to just `suppressions.xml` in checkstyle-config.xml but didn't work. Got Unable to find the file error in this case.

Comment: I never used one. So I can't help here. You should probably put that XML in the question by editing it.

Comment: Resolved it. The issue was in the suppressions.xml itself. Removed the "/**" from files attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

The `files` attribute is a regular expression which is evaluated against the absolute file paths of the files checked. So the `**` expression is invalid. Use something like this instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="JavadocPackage" files="[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]java[/\\].*"/>
</suppressions>
```

Using `[/\\]` instead of just `/` also supports both UNIX and Windows path separators.